# Auth.authenticate never returns positive Django

Tags: python, django, database, authentication

I have a login system with user who has an email of `test@test.test` but whenever I try this system it always returns "None"

```
    if request.method=="POST":

        email=request.POST.get('email','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)
        print(email)
        print(password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            print("notNone")
            auth.login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
        else:
            print("None")
            context={
                "failure":"Password and e-mail did not match",
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
```

Even if I do `auth.authenticate(email=email)`, or `auth.authenticate(email="test@test.test")`, it ALWAYS returns none. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the password is for that user with the specified email address?

Answer (score 1):

Django's [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) method checks against a `username`, not an email.

> It takes credentials in the form of keyword arguments, for the default configuration this is **username** and password.

The simple solution to this is, when defining a user, set their username to the same as the email.